# Website works while remote debugging on an iPhone but not without debugger attached

Tags: mobile-safari

I have a website which on an old iPhone shows only a skeleton loading screen and nothing happens and when I connect Safari on a MacBook and use a Web Inspector to see the console the website works as expected.

Anybody had any idea what is the problem or how to get to the bottom of this?